# Looking for the quickest way to find the value of a column given an index for all rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a more efficient way to grab acertain value at a certain index for every row in a Pandas DataFrame than the one I have currently. Here's the code I have so far. The .apply() function with the lambda syntax is super slow so would love a more optimised version.

Let me know if you need more info/context, thanks!

```
def find_session_time_given_index(df, value):
    """
    Finds the minutes_in_session value where its corresponding index is the same as the value
    where the last true exists in the column last_true_index. Used in modify_events_table() in a .apply.
    :param df: pd.DataFrame
    :param value: row in .apply()
    :return: int
    """
    last_true = value["last_true_index"]
    return list(df[df["index"] == last_true]["minutes_in_session"])[0]

df["last_true_index"] = df["index"].mul(df["same_user_new_session"]).cummax()
df["minutes_of_last_true_index"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: find_session_time_given_index(df, x), axis=1
)
```

EDIT:
Here's an example output:

| index | timestamp | user_id | last_true_index | minutes_in_session | minutes_of_last_true_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Time1 | 1 | 0 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | Time2 | 1 | 0 | 101 | 100 |
| 11 | Time3 | 2 | 11 | 54 | 54 |
| 12 | Time4 | 2 | 11 | 55 | 54 |

The `minutes_of_last_true_index` is the column to be populated.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example with your desired output?

Comment: @Sadcow Of course, I will edit my question

Comment: Maybe I don't get your question. However, I think that in this way, it is difficult to others to help. What is your first df? in your code, you have `"same_user_new_session"' column, but I can not see that. A minimal example which shows a sample of your df, i.e contains the columns which should be used here, and 4-5 rows. You only provide the output and obviously, people can not see the progress on your df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try merging the original df with itself using `last_true_index` and `index` as keys:

```
df_new = pd.merge(df, df['minutes_in_session'].reset_index(), left_on='last_true_index', right_on='index', suffixes=('', '_'))
df_new = df_new.drop(columns=('index',))\
    .rename(columns={'minutes_in_session_':'minutes_of_last_true_index'}
```

Comment: do you mean `merge` instead of `join`?

Comment: I do not discriminate too hard between merge and join in Pandas. This is why I used join in the code and merge in the comment (corrected now). In this case both join and merge methods can to the job.

Comment: I was just confused because I was unaware that join had `left_on` and`right_on` parameters, as well as `suffixes`. It must be one of those things that is not documented.

Comment: perhaps its a pandas version thing, because I do not believe that `pd.join` exists anymore

Comment: join still exists as a DF method. But I changed the solution to merge. Thanks for the hint!